# Why does it say the printed output is longer?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a small program that prints the sum of numbers from 1 to 101  that are divisible by 5. I tried this and the output I get is just one line, but the site says the length of my printed output is 47, and it's longer than the instructor's printed output which is 4.

[image: Edx-introduction to python]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: just this 'the total sum of numbers divisible by 5 is 1050'

Comment: `len("the total sum of numbers divisible by 5 is 1050") = 47`, so you seem to be printing the length of the actual string. If you posted your code it would be much easier to help.

  Edit: after seeing your code and the error: you were supposed to print just "1050", not the sentence you printed, although that is more of a semantic problem and not an error in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't print `"the total sum of numbers divisible by 5 is"`. Just print the number. The checker doesn't like the English message.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, the sum of all integers divisible by 5 between 1 and 101 is 1050:

```
>>> def divisibles(start, end, divisor=5):
...     for i in range(start, end+1):  # Last value should be included
...         if not i % divisor:
...             yield i
... 
>>> sum(divisibles(1, 101))
1050
>>>
```